# Environment texture is not effecting(lighting) my scene

Tags: lighting, hdri, world

[image]

It's not lighting my scene, when i uncheck the scene world i can view the scene with proper light but when i use the same hdri and put it into the world property as an environment texture it doesn't affect my scene.

[image]
when i hit f12 its not rendering with the hdri lighting shown in the viewport it only renders the 2 area light.
iam not sure what iam missing i just want my render to look like the viewport is showing it looks like.
I will upload the file if you want to look at it
https://pasteall.org/blend/093e57cc2a6243e587314a5f12f4c0d7
Ps, it does work in cycles but ENV texture should also work in evee right?

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Emir, i tried that's exactly how i add the environment texture but it's just not affecting my scene. moonboots i have added the file thanks for looking into it

Comment: in the file there is no ENV texture. can you try to load into blender an env texture with a .hdr file?

Comment: I updated it i basically added the same hdri file that blender uses from the blender installation folder. sunset.exr    https://pasteall.org/blend/093e57cc2a6243e587314a5f12f4c0d7

Answer (score 3):

I baked my indirect lighting first and then added an ENV texture in, so that's why my viewport and my render was not able to capture the ENV light

Solution: Just delete the indirect lighting cache and the viewport will show the ENV lighting again. [image]